# Javascript ToDo List Delete and Complete Buttons

Tags: javascript, events, event-delegation

My [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fkhan698/pen/MLJYZZ?editors=1111https://)

So when I click the delete and complete buttons it runs these functions

```
function deleteListItem(){
   alert("Item was deleted");            
}


function completeListItem(){
   alert("This item was completed");
}
```

for both buttons. I want to know how I can use event delegation to separate these functions, that way whenever I click the complete button it isn't running both functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, when you declare `deleteButton` and `completeButton` they are both assigned the same element, the `ul`. That element contains the entire list. That is not what you want, you want to handle clicks on the buttons.  `deleteButton` should be assigned to your delete button element and your `completeButton` to your complete button element. To do this, simply use the ID of the buttons you want instead of the ID of the UL.

In you code, change this:

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById("todo");
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);
var completeButton = document.getElementById("todo");
completeButton.addEventListener("click", completeListItem);
```

To this:

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById("Remove");
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);
var completeButton = document.getElementById("Complete");
completeButton.addEventListener("click", completeListItem);
```

**EDIT:**
Since your buttons are not unique you should not use an id to add the event listener. You should use a class and assign the event listener to all the elements with the class by looping threw them. In your html add a class attribute to your buttons like this: `<button class="Remove"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`. Then handle the events this way:

```
var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Remove");
for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', deleteListItem, false);
}
var completeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("Complete");
for (var i = 0; i < completeButton.length; i++) {
        completeButton[i].addEventListener('click', completeListItem, false);
}
```

Comment: That worked for the first element which is just my sample element. But when I create a new list, it doesn't run any of the functions for the buttons.

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan Sorry I wasn't thinking ahead and simply made your current code work. You should use a class instead of an id for the buttons since an Id is supposed to be unique. Instead of .getElementById use getElementsByClassName() and in your html add the class. I will update my answer to explain better.

Comment: Besides adding a class, would make sense to add in id (maybe suffixed with incremental number). Otherwise you wouldn't be able to select the element to delete(or mark as complete)

Comment: @Pratheep a lot can be improved but I don't think it's appropriate to rewrite the entire code. Better to simply answer the question and open up a new question if needed for other parts of the code.

Comment: @NTR so... this is very weird but when I changed my html to add a class to buttons and changed  
 `document.getElementsByClassName("Remove");` and `document.getElementsByClassName("Remove");` it wouldn't even let me create a new list element. I completely get the idea behind the for loops, but now nothing is working lol

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan in your codepen you did not use the loop. If you try adding the eventlistener to a colletion of elements it won't work.

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan not sure how sharing codepens works but I took yours and made the changes in my answer and here is the working result: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPJYNw?editors=1111https://

Comment: @NTR ok so now in your codepen it creates the list with the class name, but now it won't alert when the buttons are clicked on the `li` that was created.

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan that's because the event listener is doing the assignement on load and not doing in after you add things. When you create the new item. You need to assign the event listener to that new item. Updated codepen again: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPJYNw?editors=1111https://

Comment: @NTR Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan no problem. If you could mark the answer has the accepted answer so it might help others it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById("Remove");
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);
var completeButton = document.getElementById("Complete");
  completeButton.addEventListener("click", completeListItem);
```

Assign `addEventListener` to specific `id` of the button. `id` `todo` is the `ul` so clicking anything inside `ul` will run both functions