# How to assign icon after add a list (which are added using JS)?

Tags: javascript, html

I actually want to add delete icon after adding the list item. I'm adding list items using JS. So I want to see delete icon after adding list.

```js
const viewList = () => {
  const listItem = document.getElementById('list-item');
  listItem.innerHTML = '';

  todoList.forEach((list) => {
    const listEl = document.createElement('li');
    const { toDo } = list;
    
    let title = list.toDo.text;

    listEl.textContent = title;
    listItem.append(listEl);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="show">
  <ul id="list-item"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: create a delete icon with functionality in js and append it to listEl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a template literal to create the HTML text to feed to the `innerHTML` property of the new `<li>`.

To remove the list item, you can referencing the `<button>`'s parent `<li>`.

I created a global function on the `window` called `handleRemove`. You can set this as the click handler on each of the "Remove" buttons.

```js
const todoList = [
  { toDo : { text: 'Wake up' } },
  { toDo : { text: 'Eat' } },
  { toDo : { text: 'Go to sleep' } }
]

const viewList = () => {
  const listItem = document.getElementById('list-item');
  listItem.innerHTML = '';

  todoList.forEach(({ toDo: { text: title } }) =>
    listItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <li class="todo-item">
        <span>${title}</span>
        <button onclick="handleRemove(this)">Remove</button>
      </li>
    `));
}

viewList();

function handleRemove(button) {
  button.closest('li').remove(); // Remove the parent <li>
}
```

```css
.todo-item {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.todo-item > span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="show">
  <ul id="list-item"></ul>
</div>
```

You could simply your `viewList` function to this:

```js
const viewList = () =>
  document.getElementById('list-item').innerHTML = todoList
    .map(({ toDo: { text: title } }) => `
      <li class="todo-item">
        <span>${title}</span>
        <button onclick="handleRemove(this)">Remove</button>
      </li>
    `).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an EventListener
[Javascript ToDo List Delete and Complete Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565161/javascript-todo-list-delete-and-complete-buttons)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you do it the exact same way you made `listEL`, after you append `listEL`:

```
listItem.append(listEl);
// Add icon after
const deleteIcon = //make a delete icon using DOM manipulation code
listItem.append(deleteIcon);
```

For instance, if your `deleteIcon` was a `<span class="delete-icon"/>`, you could do:

```
listItem.append(listEl);
// Add icon after
const deleteIcon = document.createElement('li');
deleteIcon.classList.add('delete-icon');
listItem.append(deleteIcon);
```